# Add custom TreeNode with child Nodes to TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a couple of files containing a header and some data, and I want to create a ViewTree based on the information in the header. (Following is just an example code, the real code is much longer.)

The files (example only)

```
DataFile 1      DataFile 2      DataFile 3      DataFile 4          etc.
Net    1        Net    1        Net    1        Net    2        
Sub    1        Sub    2        Sub    2        Sub    1
Node   1        Node   1        Node   2        Node   1
```

Following code does add the information from the header to a ViewTree, the problem comes when I want to use a selected TreeViewNode (futher down in this question)

DataFile class

```
public class DataFile
{
    public enum Header
    {
        NET,
        SUB,
        NODE
    }

    public string FilePath { get; set; }

    public DataFile(string path) { FilePath = path; }

    public string HeaderValue(int row) 
    {
        return File.ReadLines(this.FilePath, Encoding.Default).Skip(row).First().Split('\t')[1];
    }
}
```

myNode class

```
public class myNode : DataFile
{
    public string Net { get { return HeaderValue((int)Header.Net); } }
    public string Sub { get { return HeaderValue((int)Header.Sub); } }
    public string Node { get { return HeaderValue((int)Header.Node); } }

    public myNode(string path):base(path: path) { }
}
```

I populate the TreeView using following function

```
public static void PopulateTree(TreeView tree, string searchpath)
{
    foreach(string datafile in Directory.GetFiles(searchpath, "datafile.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        myNode node = new myNode(datafile);

        if (!tree
            .Nodes.ContainsKey(node.Net))
        {
            tree
                .Nodes.Add(node.Net, node.Net);
        if (!tree
            .Nodes[node.Net]
            .Nodes.ContainsKey(node.Sub))
        {
            tree
                .Nodes[node.Net]
                .Nodes.Add(node.Sub, node.Sub));
        }
        if (!tree
            .Nodes[node.Net]
            .Nodes[node.Sub]
            .Nodes.ContainsKey(node.Node))
        {
            tree
                .Nodes[node.Net]
                .Nodes[node.Sub]
                .Nodes.Add(node.Node, node.Node));
        }
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
}
```

This give me the following TreeView structure

```
1
├─1
│ └─1
└─2
  ├─1
  └─2
2
└─1
  └─1
```

Everything is fine but not very useful. I want the nodes to contain data properties with values from the DataFile. So I decided to make my own TreeNode class as follow

```
public class myTreeNode : TreeNode
{
    private enum Header
    {
        NET,
        SUB,
        NODE
    }

    public string SearchPath { get; set; }
    public string Net { get; set; }
    public string Sub { get; set; }
    public string Node { get; set; }

    public string HeaderValue(int row) 
    {
        return File.ReadLines(this.SearchPath, Encoding.Default).Skip(row).First().Split('\t')[1];
    }

    public myTreeNode(string searchpath):base()
    {
        SearchPath = searchpath;
        Net = HeaderValue((int)Header.Net);
        Sub = HeaderValue((int)Header.Sub);
        Node = HeaderValue((int)Header.Node);
    }
}
```

I do a similar function to populate my TreeView

```
myNode customNode = new myNode(datafile);

if (!tree
    .Nodes.ContainsKey(customNode.Net))
    tree
        .Nodes.Add(customNode.Net, customNode.Net));
etc.
```

And it populates my TreeView as the previous function did.

**Question:** How can I access my customized TreeNode from for example NodeMouseDoubleClick? I try passing myNode to a function from the event but I get exception Cannot convert TreeNode to type myNode.

example

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    myFunction((myNode)treeView1.SelectedNode); // also tried without (myNode) but got same exeption.
}
```

Comment: _save draft_ happens automatically.

Comment: @TaW Ok thanks didn't know that and did not want to risk it

Comment: Does this `(myNode)(treeView1.SelectedNode)` also crash?It is often a good idea to pull nested references apart: `myNode n = treeView1.SelectedNode as myNode; if (n!=null)..;` Which exception do you get?

Comment: @TaW No, the application doesn't crasch. I use try catch with a messagebox showing the exception message. It reads `Cannot convert from System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode to myNode`.

Comment: Well, that means that it doesn't contain your custom net class but only a normal node. I see you add the `string node.Net`, which does extaclty that: Add a normal Node, not your type.. Change `.Nodes.Add(customNode.Net));` to `.Nodes.Add(customNode));`